# Jenkins-CI github push triggers

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I'm trying to setup our organization on jenkins. 
So far I got three different methods and all are lacking some features:

1. add single jobs for each repo, is working fine with github webhook and build on pushes, but for each new branch/PR I need to add it manually, thats not an option
2. adding workflow pipeline, is getting all branches from github, but has no option for "build on push" as 1., and I can't add any github webhooks and I need to add every repo manually
3. adding github organization folder, very nice I don't need to add every repo, but as 2. can't add any "build on push" build triggers and running on polling is running into api rate limits (and polling sucks for this case..)

So regarding I didn't missed any option, here what I want to achieve:

Github organization folder and getting github webhooks (build on push/create new branches/PRs) would be the best case, without polling every x minutes.

If thats not possible, at least option 2. with "push build triggers"

Ah and I tried to add a jenkins trigger url with authToken, but every time I set an authToken and press save its not saved.. (checkbox remains unchecked)

Comment: thanks. Jenkins has all these help bubbles... But I can still never figure out what's going on

Answer (score 2):

Ok after some sleep (perhaps this helped) I just figured it out.

1. Setup your github organization folder
2. Go to Github and go to your ORGANIZATION->Settings->webhooks and add the webhook url (with user:password@, that was defined at Manage-Jenkins->Configure-System->Github hooks url) with your shared secret.
3. Push something in your repo and voila.. its building automatically

So the magic is here, to add the webhook to the organization and not to the repo.